# multiple count in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a litte question.. i got a mysql-table

```
cat | item |  data |
100 |   0  |   10  |
102 |   1  |   3   |
101 |   1  |   1   |
100 |   0  |   40  |
100 |   1  |   20  |
102 |   0  |   3   |
101 |   1  |   2   |
100 |   0  |   30  |
102 |   1  |   3   |
```

and my query looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT cat, COUNT(item) FROM table WHERE item=0 GROUP BY cat";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['COUNT(item)'].''.$row['COUNT(cat)'];
}
```

how does it work that i count item by 0 and 1 at the same time?

i want it like this

```
categories |   items 0  |   items 1
100        |     3      |     1 
101        |     0      |     2 
102        |     1      |     2
```

sorry for my bad english :/ 
hope you understand my problem

best regards bernte

---

Thanks for helping james_bond and bfavaretto

is there a whay to do an other rule? 
i want the sum of data for item 0 and item 1

```
categories |   data 0  |   data 1
100        |     80    |     20 
101        |     0     |     3 
102        |     3     |     6
```

i tried it with the code of james_bond without success :(

best regards bernte

Comment: Open up another question, if you keep editing your question this will be an never ending situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  cat, SUM(IF(item = 0,1,0)) AS items0,  SUM(IF(item = 1,1,0)) AS items1 FROM table GROUP BY cat
```

Comment: thanks for the tip :D sorry i'm new with stackoverflow :D
i asked the new question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630748/multiple-sum-for-row

Answer (score 7):

```
$query = "SELECT cat, SUM(CASE WHEN item=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS items_0, SUM(item) AS items_1 FROM table GROUP BY cat";
```