# Multiple SUM for row

Tags: php, mysql

I have another little question.  I have a mysql-table

```
cat | item |  data |
100 |   0  |   10  |
102 |   1  |   3   |
101 |   1  |   1   |
100 |   0  |   40  |
100 |   1  |   20  |
102 |   0  |   3   |
101 |   1  |   2   |
100 |   0  |   30  |
102 |   1  |   3   |
```

james_bond helped me with this code:

```
SELECT  cat, SUM(IF(item = 0,1,0)) AS items0,  
    SUM(IF(item = 1,1,0)) AS items1 FROM table GROUP BY cat
```

I get the result:

```
categories |   items 0  |   items 1
100        |     3      |     1 
101        |     0      |     2 
102        |     1      |     2
```

**Now I need another rule to get the following result:**

I want the sum of data for item 0 and item 1:

```
categories |   data 0  |   data 1
100        |     80    |     20 
101        |     0     |     3 
102        |     3     |     6
```

I would be happy if someone could help me.

Comment: Just sum up the `data` column in the same way you do with your `item` column. It's not that hard, try coming up with a solution for this one based on your existing solution yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a similar query:

```
SELECT 
  cat, 
  SUM(IF(item = 0,data,0)) AS data0,  
  SUM(IF(item = 1,data,0)) AS data1 
FROM table GROUP BY cat;
```